# BeautifulSoup returns nothing even though the element exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.flaconi.de/haare/maria-nila/head-and-hair- 
heal/maria-nila-head-and-hair-heal-haarshampoo.html#sku=80021856- 
100')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')


soup.find('div', class_ = 'average-rating')
```

it returns nothing. I am sure there is a content from website

Comment: Your code is not printing or assigning to a variable - are you sure its returning nothing or are you perhaps just not doing anything (sorry - I can't think of a nice way to phrase this).

Comment: it returns nothing.

Comment: Its pretty strange results you get from driver.page_source - not so clear. A lot of javascript going on.

Comment: I think bs4 is defeated by the javascript in this case (the page source and the rendered page are not the same thing, I guess). You should go with selenium as indicated below - that works better.

Comment: In page source there are not this class average-rating i think it will render with javascript. Use selenium selectores as said @Chris.

Answer (score 1):

That value is stored in a script tag. You can regex it out from response.text though I would escape the html entities first to make regex more readable

```
import requests, re, html

r = requests.get('https://www.flaconi.de/haare/maria-nila/head-and-hair-heal/maria-nila-head-and-hair-heal-haarshampoo.html#sku=80021856-100')
avg_rating = round(float(re.search(r'"ratingValue":(.*?),', html.unescape(r.text)).group(1)), 1)
print(avg_rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use BS here.  Selenium can find the element no problem.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.flaconi.de/haare/maria-nila/head-and-hair-heal/maria-nila-head-and-hair-heal-haarshampoo.html#sku=80021856-100')

driver.find_element_by_class_name('average-rating').text
```

Output

```
4.8
```

Comment: sorry. the result I got is "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".average-rating"} (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.75)"